# imagettfbbox() returns wrong dimensions when using space characters inside text

Tags: php, imagettftext

I'm creating a graphical menu dynamically from PHP, it results in only 1 image that looks like this:

```
One    Two    Three    Four
```

The problem however is, that I have to determine the x-offset and the width of each page title (e.g. the left offset and the width of "One" in pixels) to position the image with css.

All works fine, except for page titles that contain spaces - imagettfbbox() returns the wrong positions. I am using an arial font (TTF)

Any suggestions on how I get around this issue?

Edit: I got it working now, using the following function to determine the text's bounds:

```
function calculateTextBox($font_size, $font_angle, $font_file, $text) {
    $box = imagettfbbox($font_size, $font_angle, $font_file, $text);

    $min_x = min(array($box[0], $box[2], $box[4], $box[6]));
    $max_x = max(array($box[0], $box[2], $box[4], $box[6]));
    $min_y = min(array($box[1], $box[3], $box[5], $box[7]));
    $max_y = max(array($box[1], $box[3], $box[5], $box[7]));

    return array(
        'left' => ($min_x >= -1) ? -abs($min_x + 1) : abs($min_x + 2),
        'top' => abs($min_y),
        'width' => $max_x - $min_x,
        'height' => $max_y - $min_y,
        'box' => $box
    );
}
```

Edit 2: Unfortunately I keep getting wrong dimensions when using different font sizes and font files...

Comment: You should show some code. Is the imagettfbbox manual example working on your system? It precisely illustrates using the function with text including spaces.

Comment: Link to the source is now in the post

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to use the [imagecolorat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php) function to work out the colour of a pixel at particular point in the image, its not going to be the quickest or even necessarily the best way to do it but it should work.

Something like this (searching for black pixels) should work, and will return the bounds you're looking for which you can then translate into x/ co-ordinates if you want:

```
function get_bounds($image)
{
    $height = imagesy($image);
    $width = imagesx($image);


    $to_return = new stdClass();
    $to_return->top = null;
    $to_return->bottom = null;
    $to_return->left = null;
    $to_return->right = null;

    for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++)
    {
        for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++)
        {
            $color = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
            $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($image, $color);

            // If its black
            if (($rgb['red'] == 0) && ($rgb['green'] == 0) && ($rgb['blue'] == 0))
            {
                if (($y < $to_return->top) || is_null($to_return->top))
                {
                    $to_return->top = $y;
                }

                if (($y > $to_return->bottom) || is_null($to_return->bottom))
                {
                    $to_return->bottom = $y;
                }

                if (($x < $to_return->left) || is_null($to_return->left))
                {
                    $to_return->left = $x;
                }

                if (($x > $to_return->right) || is_null($to_return->right))
                {
                    $to_return->right = $x;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $to_return;
}
```

Comment: Although this will work out the overall sizes of your font within the image. I'd assume that the "imagettfbbox" that you're having problems with is doing the same and giving you overall dimensions rather than ones for each individual word (if that's what you're after). If that is the case then I'm not sure there is a way to work out where the individual words are.. perhaps detecting large gaps between pixels using the colorat method?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, its real bounds can be calculated from  [imagettftext](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext)  function's return values.